# How to implement Struts 2 i18n with plain Arabic text?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, internationalization

I am using Struts 2, there is a requirement for i18n, I have created global & global_ar property files, for English all the characters are showing properly, and previously I converted all Arabic text into UTF-8 code that time application works good, but when I change that to plain Arabic text its stops working, in browser for Arabic text its shows some weird characters.

### JSP File

```jsp
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%> 
<%@ taglib prefix="t" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/custom_tag"%> 
<t:template> 
   <s:form action="visitations.action" id="visitationForm" theme="simple" method="post">  </s:form>     
<s:text name="country" />:<span class="required">*</span>
</t:template>
```

Comment: Can you show your JSP page?

Comment: Yeah sure, this is my sample jsp `<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="t" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/custom_tag"%>

<t:template> <s:form action="visitations.action" id="visitationForm"
   theme="simple" method="post"></s:form><s:text name="country" />:<span
       class="required">*</span></t:template>`

Comment: is your application is for multiple locale or only for Arabic?

Comment: Why did you change that to plain Arabic text? Is this a main cause of the error?

Comment: @Roman C Actually I joined in this project at middle, I don't know why they put all these values in properties file, in my previous project we do store and retrieve from data base. for client frequent changes on labels, i think thery ask to do so.

Comment: @Umesh Awasthi Our Application supports both English & Arabic. English text works properly, due to this Unicode issue Arabic text fails but I don't know how to fix this issue, any help.

Comment: @salz From the database you retrive and store the values that user enter on forms but the labels, messages, other UI elements has values that come from the resources supplied with the application. Localization means you could easily  switch the UI names to replace it with requested locale. And it works fine except that the text should be properly encoded.

Comment: @RomanC My previous project was ERP app, we can't manage all labels in property file, so we have to store all labels and message in database, while the application start we have supplied values to bundle through contextInitialized method, that is entirely different story and easy to implement, please do you have any ideas in this issue, so it can be so helpful to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `native2ascii` to convert charset to ASCII. This is required encoding for the message resources.

Suppose `resources` is a first dir under the `src` folder which contains message properties files that you need to convert. Using `ant`

```xml
<target name="native2ascii">
  <delete dir="${classes.dir}/resources" includes="*.properties" />
  <native2ascii encoding="cp1256" src="${source.dir}/resources" dest="${classes.dir}/resources" includes="*.properties" />
  <copy todir="${exploaded.dir}/WEB-INF/classes/resources">
    <fileset dir="${classes.dir}/resources" includes="*.properties" />
  </copy>
</target>
```

---

Run this script on each build, you should probably customize it to translate it properly choosing encoding charset that a file is natively encoded.

You can find some character encodings supported by JVM: [Character Encoding](http://www.cs.mun.ca/~michael/java/jdk1.1-beta2-docs/guide/intl/html/intlspec.doc7.html).

Comment: If there is a chance for me to change text into ASCII then I'll be using Uni-Code itself in my property file, requirement is only with plain Arabic text I need to render to browser.

Comment: Do you mean UTF8 encoding or something else?

Comment: Yeah UTF8 encoding itself, we have never written any class for i18n, we have only configure in struts.xml file, and its working good for English text.

Comment: Use this value in the `encoding` attribute in my script and it will convert it, you should try it yourself.

Comment: Yeah that's the main issue with my manager, If I say anything about conversion, he start jumping at me, he says what to do if client sends label ie translation text each day, it should be easier to adopt. But your answer really makes sense, but they can't understand.

Comment: Message resources are built into application war file, and translation required on each build that's why you should use ant build script. Usually it's required if the application is modified, recompiled, rebuilt. You should not change this files if it's already built.

Comment: Good, but I bound with lot of exceptions in my company, let me suggest your solution, really you helped a lot, thanks for that.